# Ctrl key is broken on HP Envy is broken, where can I find a replacement

Tags: keyboard, hp-envy

I work as a developer so I have to use key combinations a lot. And I have HP Envy laptop. 
And the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is broken for the second time.

First time I just took one from my friend. But I don't have any more friends who are willing to sacrifice their <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key

Anyone know where I can find one?  (or rather a bunch because they are so weak and low quality)

I tried to contact HP support but they did everything to prevent people from doing it. And it is impossible to reach HP support. And in my case where warranty is expired it is not possible at all according to their rules.

Also I tried Googling but found nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [LaptopKey](http://www.laptopkey.com/). They offer single keyboard keys and ship worldwide.

> #### Are you missing a key on your laptop?
>
> No Problem; you don't have to replace the whole keyboard. We sell single key(s) replacement kits: Key Cap, Plastic Hinges and Rubber Cup for your missing laptop key.